# What is the size of soul according to Quran?

Tags: soul

From Quran, it is clear that soul exists.

But is there any mentioning in Quran about the size/ volume of soul of human being?

If Quran says about size/ volume of souls, then is the size/ volume for humans and non-humans same?

If quran doesn't  mentioned explicitly about volume of soul. Please refer islamic texts explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there any mentioning in Quran about the size/ volume of soul of human being?

No. Quran doesn't mention about size or volume of the soul.

In fact it is not a physical thing, hence cannot be measured. This shall help you better understand it. http://www.irfi.org/articles/articles_51_100/nature_of_soul.htm